# Fatal error when changing field type using hook_form_alter

Tags: 7, forms

I'm currently trying to override a custom field within a Taxonomy Vocab via hook_form_alter()

I have configured a text field with the machine name "field_hex", and I'm trying to change the type to 'jquery_colorpicker' (when a user adds /edits a term), so that the user can use a jQuery Colorpicker to enter a hex value.

**$form['field_hex']['#type'] = 'jquery_colorpicker';**

Overriding the field type using hook_form_alter using the code above displays the colour picker, but when you click "Save" and submit the form, I get the following Fatal error:

**Fatal error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor overloaded objects in /var/www/mysite/includes/common.inc on line 6448**

I noticed that the field type before I override the value for this field is "container" and not "textfield" as I would've expected. I'm not sure if this means anything?

Also, I tried changing the field type to "textarea" and I get the same error when I submit the form so it can't be the 'jquery_colorpicker' value causing problems.

Any help / direction would be greatly appreciated!!

**## UPDATE ISSUE SOLVED! ##**

It seems I was referencing the form array incorrectly when trying to change the form item type. When trying to change a form item type, always remember to reference the language portion too:

**$form['field_hex'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#type'] = 'FIELD_TYPE_HERE';**